# Strange error reported in this code, please explain?

Tags: vb.net, wmi

I put together this bit of code from a few other samples, and I am getting an error I cant understand. On this line in the code below, on the word Observer,

```
Dim Results As ManagementObjectCollection = Worker.Get(Observer)
```

I get the error 
"Value of type 'System.Management.ManagementOperationObserver' cannot be converted to 'Integer'"

Can somebody explain what this means?

There are two signatures for ManagementObjectSearcher.Get(), one has no parameters and the other has one parameter, a ManagementOperationObserver for async operation. That is what I am providing, yet the error indicates conversion involving an integer?

```
    Public Shared Sub WMIDriveDetectionASYNC(ByVal args As String())

        Dim Observer As New ManagementOperationObserver()
        Dim completionHandler As New MyHandler()
        AddHandler Observer.Completed, AddressOf completionHandler.Done

        Dim Machine = "192.168.0.15"
        Dim Scope = New ManagementScope("\\" & Machine & "\root\cimv2")
        Dim QueryString = "select Name, Size, FreeSpace from Win32_LogicalDisk where DriveType=3"
        Dim Query = New ObjectQuery(QueryString)
        Dim Worker = New ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, Query)
        Dim Results As ManagementObjectCollection = Worker.Get(Observer) 'use parameter to make async 

        For Each item As ManagementObject In Results
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {2} {1}", item("Name"), item("FreeSpace"), item("Size"))
            Dim FullSpace As Long = (CLng(item("Size")) - CLng(item("FreeSpace"))) \ 1000000
            Console.WriteLine(FullSpace)
        Next

    End Sub

Public Class MyHandler
        Private _isComplete As Boolean = False

        Public Sub Done(sender As Object, e As CompletedEventArgs)
            _isComplete = True
        End Sub 'Done

        Public ReadOnly Property IsComplete() As Boolean
            Get
                Return _isComplete
            End Get
        End Property

End Class
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: What does `Worker.Get` look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that uses a reference type to get the result and put it in the object you sent as a parameter.  So I think it just needs to look like:

```
Worker.Get(Observer)
```

instead of trying to set something = to that since it isn't a function that returns a value.

Then use the events you hook up to the object to handle whatever you need to do with the items you find.

Comment: Thanks very much D, embarrassingly obvious once you mention it though.